# Render WMS at fixed scale (static image effect)

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, rendering

I have a point layer that I'm rendering as a WMS using GeoServer, the points look like a continuous surface and 'blend' great at about 1:10 000. I want to keep the WMS rendered at that scale, irrespective of the client's zoom level. So if the user is zoomed out at 1:5 000 000 or zoomed in at 1:500, the WMS must remain at zoom level 1:10 000. I currently deal with this using scale ranges and rules in an SLD, but surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking goes against the WMS specification, the server must do what the client asks for, if the client asks for 1:20k, the server must answer at 1:20k.

I have the impression the points are there just to achieve a visual effect, if so, share the output you want to get and we can discuss of different ways to get the same (if any exists).